# Are there any reliable implementations of ElGamal public key crypto in Java?

Tags: java, cryptography

I need to use ElGamal for a project of critical importance in terms of confidentiality. 
My frustration is that I have not been able to find a reliable, industry-tested implementation of ElGamal asymmetric encryption in Java. I have found these so far:

- https://github.com/Ananasr/Cryptology
- http://faculty.washington.edu/moishe/javademos/Security/ElGamal.java

They do not seem reliable and well-maintained to me. 
Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you have a look at BouncyCastle?

Comment: You may want to ask on Crypto.SE though whether ElGamal is actually the right and best solution to the problem you're having, given that it's usually only good in a select few, exotic situations.

Answer (score 1):

As @SEJPM notes in the comments, the well-known [Bouncy Castle library](https://www.bouncycastle.org/java.html) has an implementation of [ElGamal asymmetric encryption](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~jonah/bc/org/bouncycastle/crypto/engines/ElGamalEngine.html). [Here](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?api=org.bouncycastle.crypto.engines.ElGamalEngine) are some examples of how to use it.

I've successfully used Bouncy Castle in a few projects so far, but not this particular type of encryption, so I can't comment on the specific reliability of this component.